# Hibernate, using distinct with more than one column inside count

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

How could I rewrite SQL query showed below into HQL? I would like to use `javax.persistence.Query`

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(book_id, author_id)) FROM dbo.book bo
 LEFT JOIN dbo.author au ON au.id = bo.author_id
 LEFT JOIN dbo.publisher pu ON pu.id = bo.publisher_id
 WHERE pu.id = 777`

My attempt which does not work:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(bl.id, o.id)) FROM PRDAuthor as o 
 LEFT JOIN FETCH o.bookList as bl
 WHERE bl.publisher.id = 777`

EDIT: I am attaching my entities

**PRDAuthor**

```
public class PRDAuthor {

    // ...
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "author", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @BatchSize(size = 100)
    private List<PRDBook> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...
}
```

**PRDBook**

```
public class PRDBook {

    // ...
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @BatchSize(size = 30)
    private PRDAuthor author;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @BatchSize(size = 30)
    private PRDPublisher publisher;

    // ...
}
```

**PRDPublisher**

```
public class PRDPublisher {

    // ...
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "publisher", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @BatchSize(size = 100)
    private List<PRDBook> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count only by one field
Try this one (not tested):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(*)) FROM PRDAuthor as o 
LEFT JOIN FETCH o.bookList as bl
WHERE bl.publisher.id = 777
```

Comment: I received `unexpected token )`. I am not sure if it is possible to use * with `DISTINCT` in that way. Even if it does not cause an error, I think that it can not help me reach what I would like. Let's say that pure SQL query which I had attached, but without count, results in 4 rows: (1000, 1), (2000, 1), (3000, 1) and (2000, 2). HQL query similar to your will count it as 3, beacuse, after all, there are three PRDBook objects (1000, 2000 and 3000). But I am not sure if I am right.

Comment: try `COUNT(*)` without `DISTINCT`